# how to know from adapter if the item of ListView is visible or not?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, baseadapter

I have an adapter that connected to ListView, e.g.

```
mJournalAdapter = new JournalAdapter();
journalEntryList.setAdapter(mJournalAdapter);
```

and I want to know inside of my `JournalAdapter` if some view (item of ListView) is visible or not, is it possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you know the postion of that item then you can use

```java
int last = listView1.getLastVisiblePosition();  

int first = listView1.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get callback , overriding `OnDetachedFromWindow()`; method in View

Comment: That's not how you are supposed to do in the `ListView`. You're reinventing the wheel. The other 2 answers are legit.

Comment: It's not reinventing the wheel. In fact, it is very a nice way to handle view recycling de-coupled from the listview/recyclerview/adapter

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`getFirstVisiblePosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) will give you the first visible Item in the ListView, so you can use that in your case.